# How many times has Wolverine lost his memories?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

I always laugh with my friends whenever Wolverine loses his memories. Fire an Adamantium bullet on his head or blow out his body.. He loses his memories & start gaining it over time.

I want to know how many times he has suffered this loss.

Comment: I used to know, but I forgot.

Comment: You could ask him but, wait, no that won't work...

Answer (score 3):

Wolverine has had his memories manipulated so many times its hard to keep track which is really memory loss and not just normal manipulation.  But I believe the total number is around 4 or 5 for actual memory loss and another 10 or so for memory manipulation.

The following article from the marvel Wiki does not give issues specified but would imagine most of the first memory losses mentioned should be covered by Wolverine: Origins.

[source](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine_%28James_%22Logan%22_Howlett%29)

Comment: I was looking for something with comic and story reference... not just numbers.

Comment: I doubt anyone, even a dedicated Wolverine fan is going to make the effort to come through the horrifying complex, constantly modified, regularly retconned history of Wolverine to track the number of times he has lost his memory. Writers use his loss of memory to start stories and will likely invent new memory losses as necessary.

Comment: @Thaddeus - ouch. if even you.... :(

Comment: @Thaddeus do we even know what the current state of play is with his memories?